# How to obtain a value from inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I will be implementing multiprocessing so that the loops are occurring at the same time, but how can I make it so at the end of each iteration, I can obtain the value of `westernEurope.cases` and `easternEurope.cases` so that I can add them together

```
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 1000, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0)
while westernEurope.deaths < westernEurope.population:
    westernEurope.infection()
    if westernEurope.cases > westernEurope.population:
        westernEurope.cases = westernEurope.population
    print("Infections:", westernEurope.cases)    
    westernEurope.death()
    if westernEurope.deaths > westernEurope.population:
        westernEurope.deaths = westernEurope.population
    print("Deaths:", westernEurope.deaths)
    #where i want to return the value of westernEurope.cases
    time.sleep(0.1)

easternEurope = Region("Eastern Europe", 1000, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0)
while easternEurope.deaths < easternEurope.population:
    easternEurope.infection()
    if easternEurope.cases > easternEurope.population:
        easternEurope.cases = easternEurope.population
    print("Infections:", easternEurope.cases)    
    easternEurope.death()
    if easternEurope.deaths > easternEurope.population:
        easternEurope.deaths = easternEurope.population
    print("Deaths:", easternEurope.deaths)
    # where i want to return the value of easternEurope.cases
    time.sleep(0.1)

print(easternEurope.cases + westernEurope.cases)
```

Comment: One way is to write the values to a file in one process and then read that file in other process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there is no need for multiprocessing. With a generator, your problem can be solved in an even more elgant way.

```
# where i want to return the value of easternEurope.cases
yield region.cases
```

Full code:

```
def desease(region: Region):
    while region.deaths < region.population:
        region.infection()
        if region.cases > region.population:
            region.cases = region.population
        print("Infections:", region.cases)
        region.death()
        if region.deaths > region.population:
            region.deaths = region.population
        print("Deaths:", region.deaths)
        # where i want to return the value of easternEurope.cases
        yield region.cases
        time.sleep(0.1)


easternEurope = Region("Eastern Europe", 1000, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0)
westernEurope = Region("Western Europe", 2000, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0)
eastDesease = desease(easternEurope)
westDesease = desease(westernEurope)
for eastCases, westCases in zip(eastDesease, westDesease):
    print(eastCases, westCases)
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe use `zip` or `zip_longest` instead of `while` and `next`?

Comment: Yesterday I realised that I could approach it without multiprocessing, and I did change it around a bit - quite similar to yours. But you once seems to be a bit more efficient than my one, especially since it's more maintained. I appreciate the help, and thank you very much